# GoogleAppScriptでスプレットシートから文字式がうまく取得できない。

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

**したいこと**
スプレットシートの情報を取得し、複数のdiscordのチャンネルに文章として送信するプログラムをしばらく使用していました。

そこで、discordに送信する文章の内容を増やしたいとおもいました。
今までは各々のdiscordのチャンネルに数値であるhaisintimeという値だけを変えてそれぞれに送信していましたが、今回もう一つ数値の値と、文字式を送ろうと思い、get_value()関数にallpointとcomrankという変数を作り、スプレットシートから取得して送信しようとしました。

**できなかったこと**
haisintimeと同じ数値であるallpointに関してはうまくいきましたが、conrankを追加しようとした結果、エラーになりました。おそらく、文字列が問題なのかなと思ったのですが、具体的にどうすればよいかがわかりません。教えていただけると幸いです。

**試したこと**
文字列であるcomrankのところを、　getDisplayRange()で試してみたがうまくいかなかった。

```
function submit(){
  discord()
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet1 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxx',0);
    //日付
    var datecoord = sheet1.getRange(2,3);
    var date = datecoord.getValue();
      //format
    var formatcoord = sheet1.getRange(3, 3);
    var format = formatcoord.getValue();

    
    //配信時間
    var messages_array = []; // initialize
    

    
  for (let i = 11; i <= 16; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet1.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
    var pointcoord = sheet1.getRange(i,4);
    var allpoint = pointcoord.getValue();
    var rankcoord = sheet1.getRange(i, 18);
    var comrank = rankcoord.getValues();
    var message = 'None'
    if (haisintime > 0) {
      var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; var allpoint = ' + allpoint   + '; var comrank = ' + comrank + '; return ' + format + ';')();
      } 
    
    messages_array.push(message); // push
  }
  return messages_array; // return
    
  
};

//googleスプレットシート  自動送信
function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};


function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet2('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',0);

    var messages = get_value();  // call get_value() at here

    var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();  //最終行取得
    
    for (let j = 11; j <= lastRow2; j++) {

      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,3);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,4);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();
      
  　//channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,2);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();
      
    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const text       = messages[j-11];
      if (text === 'None') {
        console.log(channel + " : 送信なし"); 
        continue;
      }

      
      

      const username   = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
      const avatar_url = "http://drive.google.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
          'avatar_url' : avatar_url,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true   

      };
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    //実行ログ
    console.log(channel + " : " + text); 


    }
    
}
```

**エラー内容**

```
10:30:04    エラー 
ReferenceError: C3 is not defined
eval    
get_value   @ コード.gs:29
discord @ コード.gs:56
submit  @ コード.gs:2
```

**追記**
スプレットシートのセルC3に書かれているものはdiscordにおくる文のformatです。
今回使われている変数で例を作ってみると

"私は今年で" + haisintime + "歳になります。誕生日は" + allpoint + "です。名前は"　+ comrank + "です。"

こんな感じでC3に全部書く感じです。同じ感じで書いているのですが、comrankをいれるとうまくいかなくなる感じです。

**追記２**
必要としている情報を提示できているかわかりませんが、スプレットシートは写真のようになっています。見せられないところは消しましたが、データの配置は全く同じです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、comrankのデータは上の写真のR列のようになっています。

**追記３**
文formatが次のような場合どうすればよいでしょうか？C2の"12/1~12/5"というセルの中身を取得して文formatのdateという値に入れたいです。

"期間は" + date + "です。私は今年で" + haisintime + "歳になります。誕生日は" + allpoint + "です。名前は"　+ comrank + "です。"

出力結果ではdateという値がそのまま表示されます。
上の例で実行した結果が次です。

```
10:21:05    情報  test1 : 期間はdateです。私は今年で0歳になります。誕生日は0です。名前はDです。
10:21:06    情報  test2 : 期間はdateです。私は今年で5歳になります。誕生日は5670です。名前はC3です。
10:21:06    情報  test3 : 期間はdateです。私は今年で5歳になります。誕生日は11140です。名前はAです。
10:21:07    情報  test4 : 期間はdateです。私は今年で10歳になります。誕生日は6980です。名前はB2です。
10:21:08    情報  test5 : 期間はdateです。私は今年で6歳になります。誕生日は10です。名前はC2です。
10:21:08    情報  test6 : 期間はdateです。私は今年で0歳になります。誕生日は0です。名前はDです。
```

追記4
私は元のコードのget_value()関数を丸ごと教えていただいたものに変えました。
そうすると、以下のようにdateが薄くなっており、変数として見つからない状態になっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**追記５**
このdiscord自動送信のシステムは sheet1に数値などの値が入力されていて、
discord(message)関数のsheet2にdiscordに送信する際に必要なwebhookURLやtokenが写真のように記入されています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

名前は消してあるのでわからないかと思いますが、sheet１の名前(本来ならC列に書かれている）とsheet2の同じであり、上から順に送信すると正しい情報がデータが送信されるようになっていました。

今回、4つ目の質問のおかげでhaisintimeが0のデータは送信されないようになりました。
ただ今回のフィルターに欠けるやり方だと、上から順にhaisintimeが0でないデータが送られることになります。

例えば、

A：配信時間3時間　
B：配信時間0時間　
C：配信時間4時間　
D：配信時間5時間

というデータの場合、
A：配信時間3時間　
B：配信時間4時間　
C：配信時間5時間

となってしまうわけです。これだと違う人に違ったデータが渡ってしまいます。

A：配信時間3時間　　
C：配信時間4時間　
D：配信時間5時間

このような形にしたいのですが可能ですか？

Comment: 表示されたエラーから`get_value()`内でエラーが発生しているかもしれないと推測しました。しかし、残念ながら、関数`get_value()`と、さらに、このスクリプト(`var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; var allpoint = ' + allpoint   + '; var comrank = ' + comrank + '; return ' + format + ';')();`)で何がしたいのか理解できません。申し訳ありません。`get_value()`で何がしたいのかを理解するために、この関数に期待するサンプルの入出力データをお教えいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 本文に追記しました。よろしくお願いします。@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ならびに追加情報をありがとうございます。残念ながら`スプレットシートのセルC3に書かれているものはdiscordにおくる文のformatです。今回使われている変数で例を作ってみると"私は今年で" + haisintime + "歳になります。誕生日は" + allpoint + "です。名前は"　+ comrank + "です。"　こんな感じでC3に全部書く感じです。同じ感じで書いているのですが、comrankをいれるとうまくいかなくなる感じです。`から`get_value()`で何がしたいのか理解できませんでした。私の理解力が低く申し訳ありません。`get_value()`で何がしたいのかを理解するために、この関数に期待するサンプルの入出力データをお教えいただけないでしょうか。例えば、サンプル入力データとして、エラーを再現できるサンプルスプレッドシートを見ることができますと、理解するための材料になるのではないかと思いました。

Comment: わかりにくく、お手数をおかけします。スプレットシートの写真を追記しましたので、よろしければ再度見ていただけるとありがたいです。@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ならびに追加情報をありがとうございます。追加していただいた情報から`get_value()`を修正し、回答として提案させていただきました。ご確認ください。この他にエラーがあるかどうかは表示されたスクリプトの動作テストができないため、未確認です。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 無事実行できました。ありがとうございます。私には少々難しいコードですが、一つずつ調べ、理解していこうと思います。　もう一つお聞きしたいのですが、改行をする場合はどうすればよいでしょうか？私のコードの場合、文formatに改行したいところに\nを入れて改行していたのですが、今回のコードを実行すると、無事に\nもそのまま表示されてしまいました。どうすれば改行できるでしょうか？@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。無事に解決したとのことで安心しました。新たな質問 `もう一つお聞きしたいのですが、改行をする場合はどうすればよいでしょうか？` について、このスクリプトの場合、例えば`s.replace(...e)`を`s.replace(...e).replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`にするのはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事改行のほうもうまくいきました。何度も申し訳ありません。写真で見せた文formatの例が悪かったのですが、実は文formatに　dateという変数があり、そこに上のセルの日付が入る(写真で言えば12/1~12/5)かたちになるのですが、その場合はどのような形になるでしょうか？@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。２つ目の質問も解決したとのことで安心しました。新たな３つ目の質問ですが、残念ながら理解できたかどうかわかりません。`date`が`format`にもある場合は、例えば`format.replace(/[ 　"+]+/g, "")`を`ormat.replace(/[ 　"+]+/g, "").replace("date", date)`に変更するのはいかがでしょうか。３つ目の質問を正しく理解できたかどうか不明なため、これが正しい方向かどうかわからず、申し訳ありません。

Comment: 追記しました。何度も申し訳ありません。もしお時間があれば教えていただけると幸いです。@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。提案させていただいた３つ目の質問への回答について、問題点がありましたらその詳細をお教えいただけないでしょうか。残念ながら`追記３`とご返事からはこれについて読み取ることができませんでした。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 追記3に実行結果、問題点を書きました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事並びに追加情報をありがとうございます。３つ目の質問への回答について、ご不便をおかけして申し訳ありません。残念ながら、私の提案した３つ目の質問への回答を用いると、`"期間は" + date + "です。`の部分は、`期間は12/1~12/5です。`になり、追加情報にあるような状況を再現できません。申し訳ありません。追加された内容を正しく再現するための詳細な情報をお教えいただけないでしょうか。これにより、３つ目の質問に対する新たな回答が必要かどうかを検討したいと思います。

Comment: 追記4にコードの状況を書きました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。追加された情報を見ますと、残念ながら私の提案した３つ目の質問への回答を使用していないようです。宜しければ、私の提案した３つ目の質問への回答を試していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 無事実行することができました。一つ一つ丁寧に教えていただき、ありがとうございました。一つ一つ調べ、理解していこうと思います！

Comment: 何度も申し訳ございません。haisintimeの値が0だった時は送信しないようにしたいのですがその際はどうすればよいでしょうか？@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。３つ目の質問への回答について、無事解決したとのことで安心しました。新たな４つ目の質問について、この場合、スプレッドシートから取得した値をフィルタ処理するのはいかがでしょうか。例えば、私の回答で`var messages_array = values.map((`の部分を`var messages_array = values.filter(r => r[2] != 0).map((`にするとF列の値(`haisintime`)が0でない行を使用しますので４つ目の質問への回答としてはこれで解決できそうに思いましたがいかがでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど。そのようなやり方もあるのですね。非常に勉強になりました。無事実行ができました。本当にありがとうございました。@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。４つの質問全てについて無事に解決したとのことで安心しました。

Comment: よろしければ5つ目の質問をしてもよろしいでしょうか？何度も申し訳ありません。お時間があればよろしくお願いいたします。@Tanaike

Comment: 追記しました。お時間があればよろしくお願いいたします。@Tanaike

Comment: `よろしければ5つ目の質問をしてもよろしいでしょうか？`について、いつの間にか新たな５つ目の質問が追加されていたことに驚きました。残念ながら５つ目の質問については理解することができませんでした。これは私のスキルが低いことが原因です。申し訳ありません。様々な質問を理解できるようさらに勉強をしたいと思います。zumo1224さんから提示された４つの質問は解決できましたが、５つ目の質問に対して回答することができず本当に申し訳ありません。私の低いスキルをお許しいただければ幸いです。そこで、新たに質問をすることをお勧めしたいと思います。これにより他の多くのユーザの方々がzumo1224さんの質問について考えることができると思います。zumo1224さんの５つ目の質問を解決するために協力していただけると幸いです。協力して頂けますでしょうか。

Comment: 承知したしました。わざわざ本当にありがとうございました。@Tanaike

Comment: もしsheet2をsheet１と同じようにフィルターにかけるとするならばどのようになりますか？おそらくそれができると成功すると思います。@Tanaike

Comment: 新しく質問をしました。5つ目の質問についてより詳しく書いたのでもしわかったのであれば解決にご協力いただけると幸いです。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/84071/gas%E3%81%A7discord%E3%81%AE%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E9%80%81%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8C%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AB%E9%80%81%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84　@Tanaike

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。ご理解とご協力に感謝いたします。新たな問題として投稿されましたので、多くのユーザの方々の目に留まることで解決方法が提案される可能性を高めると思われます。

Comment: 余談で教えてほしいのですが、4つ目の質問でフィルタ処理以外の方法はあるでしょうか？例えば、　if haisintime > 0 :の時だけ送信する場合などはどのようなコードになるでしょうか？@Tanaike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

表示していただいたサンプルスプレッドシートから、スクリプトの`get_value()`の`Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; var allpoint = ' + allpoint   + '; var comrank = ' + comrank + '; return ' + format + ';')();`でエラーが発生していると考えられます。この場合、セル"R12"の値である"C3"が変数として変換されてしまうため、`C3 is not defined`のようなエラーが発生すると思いました。そこで、次のような修正を提案します。

#### Modified script:

```
function get_value() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var [[date], [format]] = sheet1.getRange("C2:C3").getValues();
  format = format.replace(/[ 　"+]+/g, "");
  var values = sheet1.getRange("D11:R" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var messages_array = values.map(([allpoint,,haisintime,,,,,,,,,,,,comrank]) =>
    Object.entries({allpoint, haisintime, comrank}).reduce((s, e) => s.replace(...e), format)
  );
  return messages_array;
}
```

修正ポイントは次の通りです。

- 複数の値を一度に`getValues`で取得するとコストを低くすることができます。
- 表示されたセル"C3"の値である`"私は今年で" + haisintime + "歳になります。誕生日は" + allpoint + "です。名前は"　+ comrank + "です。"`を`allpoint, haisintime, comrank`で置換する流れで修正しました。

#### 注意点

- 上記の修正では、V8 runtimeを有効にしていない場合はエラーが発生しますのでご注意ください。V8 runtimeを有効にしてお使いください。

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)